# Adding a column for mail aliases in script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've been playing around with a script and have it mostly working. It's using the MG graph and outputs all users in Entra ID to a csv file along with their UPN, primary email etc. One part I can't seem to get right though is adding a column for their proxy addresses. The column is always returned blank. Any ideas on how to get this working?

Tried to add this - `AdditionalSMTPAddresses = $user.ProxyAddresses` but doesn't work.

```
# Create an object to store user properties
$userObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    "First name"                  = $user.givenName
    "Last name"                   = $user.surname
    "User principal name"         = $user.userPrincipalName
    "Email address"               = $user.mail
}
```

Comment: Perhaps they are just empty? Would you share the result of `$user | Get-Member`?

Comment: Can confirm they are not empty. I may be referencing the wrong object though. My own account I can confirm has multiple smtp addresses as well as the primary SMTP one. I just want to have those listed in the output.

Comment: The command ran against my account shows this for proxy addresses. Too large to paste the whole thing but most say member type as this. "ProxyAddresses                        Property"

Comment: Pastebin(and the like) is your friend for too-large-to-paste results. That said, what command do you use to load values in `$user`?

Answer (score 1):

`proxyAddresses` is returned on `-Select` or `$select` for a Rest API call when targeting the [`v1.0` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties):

[image: doc]

So in your case you would need to select, in addition to this one, the other attributes of interest:

```bash
$properties = @(
    'givenName'
    'surname'
    'userPrincipalName'
    'mail'
    'proxyAddresses'
)

Get-Mguser -All -Select $properties | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'First name'              = $_.givenName
        'Last name'               = $_.surname
        'User principal name'     = $_.userPrincipalName
        'Email address'           = $_.mail
        'AdditionalSMTPAddresses' = $_.ProxyAddresses -join ', '
    }
}
```

Alternatively, this attribute is returned by default if targeting the [`beta` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties):

```bash
$uri = 'beta/users'
do {
    $response = Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET $uri
    $uri = $response.'@odata.nextLink'

    $response.value | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'First name'              = $_.givenName
            'Last name'               = $_.surname
            'User principal name'     = $_.userPrincipalName
            'Email address'           = $_.mail
            'AdditionalSMTPAddresses' = $_.ProxyAddresses -join ', '
        }
    }
}
while ($uri)
```

You can also use [`Get-MgBetaUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.beta.users/get-mgbetauser?view=graph-powershell-beta) if you have the `Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Users` Module to simplify the pagination process from above.